# PyQGIS Set Extent for loaded layers - Refresh problem

Tags: pyqgis, layers, zoom, mapcanvas

I've written a plugin which loads a number of map layers (based on constraints) and I would then like to set the canvas extent to a selection of them.  Code very similar to that below works perfectly, **except when** the plugin imports layers into a project with **no layers in**. If you load a single layer before running the plugin then it performs fine.

Note that code similar to below is run **after** the plugin loads in a number of new layers using for example: iface.addVectorLayer(path, 'name', 'ogr').

I've tried mapCanvas.refresh() and .repaint() within the plugin but none seem to work - what am I missing?

```
extent = QgsRectangle()
extent.setMinimal()
layers = [ iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0], iface.mapCanvas().layers()[1] ]
for layer in layers:
    extent.combineExtentWith( layer.extent() )
extent.scale( 1.1 ) # Increase a bit the extent to make sure all geometries lie inside 
iface.mapCanvas().setExtent( extent )
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Comment: Try **layers[0].triggerRepaint()**